# Invalid Sheet Identifier when trying to get shapes connected to another shape

Tags: vba, visio

I took this code directly from the VBA documentation from Microsoft, I am trying to select a shape then iterate through outgoing connected shapes.

```
Public Sub ConnectedShapes_Outgoing_Example()
' Get the shapes that are connected to the selected shape
' by outgoing connectors.
    Dim vsoShape As Visio.Shape
    Dim lngShapeIDs() As Long
    Dim intCount As Integer

    If ActiveWindow.Selection.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Please select a shape that has connections")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set vsoShape = ActiveWindow.Selection(1)
    End If

    lngShapeIDs = vsoShape.ConnectedShapes _
      (visConnectedShapesOutgoingNodes, "")
    Debug.Print "Shapes at the end of outgoing connectors:"
    For intCount = 0 To UBound(lngShapeIDs)
        Debug.Print ActivePage.Shapes(lngShapeIDs(intCount)).Name
    Next
End Sub
```

lngShapeIDs array gives me one item with an ID of 1077.

Then this:

```
Debug.Print ActivePage.Shapes(lngShapeIDs(intCount)).Name
```

...gives me an "Invalid Sheet Identifier" error, as if the ID doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Shapes collection takes an index rather than an ID.

You need Shapes.ItemFromId

Comment: Thanks, how could Microsoft get it wrong?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.connectedshapes